# Is viewing a site's unpassword protected HTTP logs/stats illegal?

Tags: legal, statistics, password

If not, why? If so, please provide US Federal code, or case law confirming this is the case.

Comment: Keep in mind that not all servers are in the USA, and the server's jurisdiction might apply. Therefore, you might get sued in North Korea, Germany, Canada, Mexico, or Russia - the laws might be slightly different there, and you may get a surprise when visiting. For an example, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/US_v._ElcomSoft_Sklyarov

Comment: @Piskvor - Interesting case, but yes, my focus is on US Federal code, or cases. Also, that case was in the US, and a federal jury found the charged parties not guilty of all four charges under the DMCA.

Comment: Good points. I was trying to find an illustration of "you can be accused of breaking a law in a country you never messed with", and this was the highest-profile case I could think of. IMO he was acquitted mainly because of the media storm that followed exposed the absurdity of the situation. It's possible that a less publicized case could have ended differently (but that's deep in "what-if" territory).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

US federal law pertaining to [Fraud and related activity in connection with computers](http://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/18/1030.html) suggests that it is unlawful to:

> intentionally access a computer
>   without authorization or exceeds
>   authorized access, and thereby obtain
>
> information contained in a financial
>   record of a financial institution, or
>   of a card issuer as defined in section
>   1602 (n) of title 15, or contained in
>   a file of a consumer reporting agency
>   on a consumer, as such terms are
>   defined in the Fair Credit Reporting
>   Act (15 U.S.C. 1681 et seq.);
>
> information from any department or
>   agency of the United States; or
>
> information from any protected
>   computer;

Whether publicly-served log files are covered is really going to depend upon the information contained in the logs (i.e. if there are requests which include sensitive data) and the definition of "protected computer".

It's generally bad practice to expose log data, however, even if the logs do not clearly contain sensitive information, I'd say it is equally bad practice to go around reading other peoples' logs (even if it's not a criminal offense, you could still run afoul of a civil court if you're somehow using someone else's "semi-private" logs to your advantage).

**Update:**

Comments seem to be primarily focused on the definitions of legal terms and that's far beyond the scope of the answer - the judicial system [hasn't](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legality_of_piggybacking#United_States) figured it out yet, either.

Comment: @danlefree - By logs, I mean HTTP access logs, or web stats. And in regards to "intentionally access a computer without authorization or exceeds authorized access" -- clearly the action would be intentional access to a computer, but access to directory/file that requires no authorization is NOT exceeding authorized access; IMHO. Make sense, or no?

Comment: I don't know that it's clearly exceeding authorized access. There are a lot of sites that broadcast their site statistics or have public logs. Google also regularly indexes unsecured logs. I think it's the webmaster's job to secure sensitive data or anything they don't want the public to have access to. If they don't and someone stumbles on it, that's the webmaster's fault. That said, the courts pretty much favor the site owners in cases like these. So even if the webmaster makes their log data publicly accessible, they can still sue others for "unauthorized access".

Comment: Although *technically*, the server needs to be (mis)configured to allow access and serve log files, IANAL. That said, clever lawyers have in the past convinced various courts that the technical details aren't important, and even though the site owners have been broadcasting their sensitive data, it's the other side's fault for reading them. So, definitely consult a lawyer before you do that.

Comment: @Lèse_majesté, @Piskvor - "Courts" does not equal case law, please reference real cases if you're going to reference cases. Thanks! (FYI - My understanding is that courts misapply trespassing laws in cases like this, but I'm unable to find in cases to reference.)

Comment: @blunders: I don't recall any specific cases ATM, sorry. If I think of some, I'll update.

Comment: @Lèse majesté - "I don't know that it's clearly exceeding authorized access." Correct, said that also, and agree that it's NOT exceeding authorized access, since access to directory/file that requires no authorization; or in plain English, password is require.

Comment: I can't cite any specific cases (I'll try to find some though), but I think it's akin to seeing an unprotected WiFi network and hopping on. Some might say that this is unauthorized access, but such an interpretation would infringe on one's right to put up a public/community AP.

Comment: @danlefree: Agree, and really like the reference to the legality of piggybacking laws regarding "unauthorized access of a computer network" exist in many legal codes, including the U.S. federal government -- which is the answer I was looking for, thanks!!